# Cannot find module /build/Debug/iconv.node

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, npm

I'm trying to run a node.js server on an Ubuntu VM.

I keep getting this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../build/Debug/iconv.node'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/api/node_modules/geoipcity/node_modules/iconv/lib/iconv.js:27:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/vagrant/api/node_modules/geoipcity/geoipcity.js:35:13)
```

The code around this line:

```
/vagrant/api/node_modules/geoipcity/node_modules/iconv/lib/iconv.js:27:14
```

Looks like this:

```
var bindings;
try {
  bindings = require('../build/Release/iconv.node');
}
catch (e) {
  bindings = require('../build/Debug/iconv.node');
}
```

The weird thing is that this file exists when I poke around my directory structure:

```
/vagrant/api/node_modules/geoipcity/node_modules/iconv/build/Release/iconv.node
```

So I'm not sure why that try catch block is ever getting to catch.  Actually, as I wrote that last sentence I decided to try to log the error that is caught.  It was:

```
[Error: /vagrant/api/node_modules/geoipcity/node_modules/iconv/build/Release/iconv.node: invalid ELF header]
```

Not sure if this is relevant, but I tried running:

```
node-gyp rebuild
```

With this result

`gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@0.13.0
gyp info using node@0.10.26 | linux | ia32
gyp info spawn python
gyp info spawn args [ '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/vagrant/api/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/0.10.26/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/vagrant/.node-gyp/0.10.26',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/vagrant/api',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.' ]
gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: /vagrant/api) while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: gyp failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:340:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:797:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-23-generic-pae
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /vagrant/api
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.26
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.13.0
gyp ERR! not ok`

Ok, that's about all I have for now.  Will keep searching for a solution and update here if I find anything new.

Thanks in advance for the help.  Oh, and please be gentle - I'm a Linux noob.

Answer (score 10):

Fixed by going to the iconv directory, and running:

```
node-gyp configure
node-gyp build
```